# Proof for function space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Why is a set of functions $$V = \{ f  |  f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R  \quad a, b \in \mathbb R \} $$ 
with the addition
$$(f+g)(x):= f(x) + g(x)$$
and with the multipilication
$$(\lambda f)(x):= f(x) \lambda$$ $ f, g \in V, \lambda \in \mathbb R$

a **vector-space** or function space?

I also have problems understanding "$(f+g)(x):=$". Does it mean, that the values of $f$ and $g$ at $x$ are added together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We **define** $f+g$ as a function on $[a,b]$. How do we define a function? By defining its value on every $x$. So we define $f+g$ evaluated at $x$ as $f(x)+g(x)$, which is obviously a real number. We define $\lambda f$ as a function in an analogous way. Now you simply have to verify that the vector space axioms hold. Hint: the "zero" in this vector space is the function $\mathbf0(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.